# Error invoking methods on EJB in WebLogic 12c: AOP configuration issue

Tags: java, weblogic, aop, jndi, ejb-3.0

I'm encountering an error when invoking a method on an EJB named "IndexingFacade" in a WebLogic 12c environment. During remote debugging, I can confirm that the correct EJB is being loaded. However, when attempting to invoke any methods on this EJB, I encounter the following error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: : 
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to 
be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract void e.e.e.a.c.IndexingFacade_ksqrhc_Intf.reindexWithNumber(java.lang.String)] on target [e.e.e.a.c.IndexingFacade_ksqrhc_Impl@bb637bb]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

The application is structured as an EAR file containing a WAR application and an EJB 3.0 module, all deployed in WebLogic 12c.

The EJB is looked up using the @EJB annotation with the beanName attribute set to "IndexingFacade". Here's how it's defined:

```
@EJB(beanName = "IndexingFacade")
private IndexingFacade facade;
```

---

```
@Local
public interface IndexingFacade {
    // Method signatures
}
```

---

```
@Stateless(name="IndexingFacade", mappedName="ejb/IndexingFacade")
public class IndexingFacadeImpl implements IndexingFacade {
    // Implementation
}
```

Even though the EJB resides within the same application and is called from within the application, it throws the AOP error mentioned above.

I have attempted to change the mappedName attribute, but it did not resolve the issue. Strangely, this setup works on another WebLogic instance, leading me to suspect a potential AOP configuration discrepancy specific to this WebLogic instance.

Could this issue be related to WebLogic AOP configuration, and are there specific configurations that need to be adjusted to resolve this problem, considering it works on another WebLogic instance? Any insights or guidance would be highly appreciated.